# How to configure SSL server authentication for WebSphere CE?

Tags: ssl, configuration, websphere, web

What I want to do is deploy a simple web application on WebSphere CE and make it work through SSL ? I generated a key and deployed an application but it works only through HTTP and doesn't work through SSL. How to enable SSL ? Please point me to the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

SSL service is listening on different port. Check servers -> application servers -> your server -> ports -> details, or something similar. You can also find these ports from a file called serverindex.xml from inside the profile directory.